# Strange Eclipse JRebel error

Tags: eclipse, jrebel

I am getting a strange error from Eclipse complaining about my rebel.xml. I deleted the project from my workspace and checked it out fresh from the repository, and am now getting this error.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd">

<classpath>
    <dir name="C:/Eclipse/workspace/MyProject/build/classes">
    </dir>
</classpath>

<web>
    <link target="/">
        <dir name="C:/Eclipse_AIJ3/workspace/MyProject/WebContent">
        </dir>
    </link>
</web>
```

Comment: The xsd might've not been available for a moment at https://update.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up closing the project, reopening, and then cleaning it to resolve this issue. Case closed.

Comment: This didn't work for a co-worker of mine, still having the exact same problem after closing, reopening the project and cleaning...

Answer (score 0):

Closing and reopening the project didn't work for me either. I found, that the URL of the XSD file changed. (See the JRebel online documentation at http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html.)

So change the xsi:schemaLocation attribute of your rebel.xml file to xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://update.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/rebel-2_1.xsd". This will fix the validation error.